# Running into undefined method from model class in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method called `calculation_of_total_cost` in `model Tippy`

It's running into problems being called in `index.html.erb` via `tippies` views directory.

This is the error I receive: `undefined method`*' for nil:NilClass`

I have googled it, and now understand that it is the result of the one of the variables being `nil`.

How do I resolve this, i.e, how do I make the method work in `index.html.erb`? This is index view that I am calling it from, so I need an instance method, not class, right?

Also, addendum: this same method works fine in `show.html.erb`

**`show.html.erb`**

```
<br/><br/>
<h1 class="text-center">Your Total Cost</h1>
<br/><br />


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Cost of Your Meal:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= humanized_money_with_symbol @tippy.cost %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Tip You Picked:
        </td>
        <td>
             <%= number_to_percentage(@tippy.tip * 100, format: "%n%", precision: 0) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            The Total Cost:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= humanized_money_with_symbol @tippy.calculation_of_total_cost %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<%= link_to 'New Tippy', new_tippy_path %>

<%= link_to "Index", tippies_path %>
```

**Here is the `Tippy` model:**

```
class Tippy < ApplicationRecord

    validates :tip, presence: true
    validates :cost, presence: true

    #monetize :tip_cents
    monetize :cost_cents, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}


    TIP_CHOICES = { "10%" => ".10", "20%" => ".20", "30%" => ".30", "40%" => ".40", "50%" => ".50", 
                    "60%" => ".60", "70%" => ".70", "80%" => ".80", "90%" => ".90" }

    def calculation_of_total_cost 
        cost + (tip * cost)
    end

end
```

**Here is the `index.html.erb` file**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Tippies</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tip</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tippies.each do |tippy| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= tippy.tip %></td>
        <td><%= tippy.cost %></td>
        <td><%= tippy.calculation_of_total_cost %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', tippy %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tippy_path(tippy) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tippy, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Tippy', new_tippy_path %>
```

**Tippy Controller**

```
class TippiesController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :set_tippy, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tippies
  # GET /tippies.json
  def index
    @tippies = Tippy.all
  end

  # GET /tippies/1
  # GET /tippies/1.json
  def show
    #@calculation_of_total_cost 
  end

  # GET /tippies/new
  def new
    @tippy = Tippy.new
  end

  # GET /tippies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tippies
  # POST /tippies.json
  def create
    @tippy = Tippy.new(tippy_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tippy.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tippy, notice: 'Tippy was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tippy }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tippy.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tippies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tippies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tippy.update(tippy_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tippy, notice: 'Tippy was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tippy }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tippy.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tippies/1
  # DELETE /tippies/1.json
  def destroy
    @tippy.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tippies_url, notice: 'Tippy was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_tippy
      @tippy = Tippy.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tippy_params
      params.require(:tippy).permit(:tip, :cost)
    end
end
```

Comment: You did not include the **tippies_controller**. Did you perform a query for filling tippies with all tippy. In your `tippies_controllers` `index` action you should have some query like `@tippies = Tippy.all` otherwise `@tippies` will have nil value

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio, just added the tippies controller, and yes, it has this query: `@tippies = Tippy.all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to set a **binding.pry** or a breakpoint at this line of index.html.erb, so that we can understand in the loop you are executing why tippy is getting value of nil. 
You need to install `pry` gem. 
Please also share the values of @tippies and the details of the other variable in the loop that fails, because tippy=nil.
An alternative for pry is just printing the value of the variable in the log with `puts tippy.calculation_of_total_cost`.

Right now I am guess is that `@tippies` which includes all `@tippy` in your `tippies` table, could have one field that has `calculation of total cost = nil`. To verifiy this you should check with the debug the value of tippy and of `tippy.calculation_of_total_cost` in the `index.html.erb` view.

```
<% @tippies.each do |tippy| %>
      <tr>
        <% binding.pry %>
        <td><%= tippy.tip %></td>
        <td><%= tippy.cost %></td>
        <td><%= tippy.calculation_of_total_cost %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', tippy %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tippy_path(tippy) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tippy, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

also it is a good idea to inspect `show.html.erb` as there it is working.

```
def calculation_of_total_cost 
    cost + (tip * cost)
end
```

Comment: ok, will try the pry gem right now. I'm not very good at using it, and debugging via that ... so, it will be an interesting to learn it!

Comment: @user273072545345 Right now I am guessing, but It may be that `@tippies` which includes all `@tippy` in your `tippies` table, could have one field that has `calculation of total cost = nil`, but right now this scenario does not make sense because it would crash before on tippy.tip or tippy.cost

Comment: oh ... so it might be faster to reset the db right now? and see if it works after that?

Comment: @user273072545345 give a look at the debug and post the result, I have no idea and I can not help you anymore. I need details about the tippy and the tippies objects.

Comment: your guess was right. I reset the db right now, and the index is now displaying just fine.

Comment: @user273072545345 Thanks a lot Very Happy that you solved it. Thanks Fabrizio